# Motherboard error possibly caused CPU damage

Tags: cpu, motherboard

My computer recently started experiencing a rather strange problem. Whenever I wake it up from sleep, the CPU fan will refuse to turn on. On traditional coolers, this would be mitigated by the thermal capacity of the heatsink, but I have a liquid cooler, and the pump is run off of the CPU fan header (it's a pre-manufactured closed loop system), so the CPU gets very hot, very fast. I know it is the CPU fan that doesn't work because my hardware monitor reports CPU fan speed of 0. Also, the other fans in the PC ramp up speed.

This has happened twice, but on the third occurrence, I suspect that some heat related CPU damage may have been incurred. After this happened for the third time, my CPU ran very sluggishly after I rebooted the computer to restart the CPU fan. It has trouble with system sounds, and even low-level system functions such as the mouse have trouble.

Something else I noticed is that this seemed to coincide with the installation of software produced by MSI, the manufacturer of my motherboard. To be specific, I was looking at the support page for my Motherboard and downloaded some software, notably MSI command center, used for fan control. (I set CPU fan to permanently be 100%.)

How do I confirm that it is the motherboard that is causing the error, and can I get the manufacturer to replace the Motherboard and CPU?

Computer details:

Case: Rosewill Redbone R3

PSU: EVGA 600B Bronze 60+

Fans: 
-1 120mm red LED
-2 120mm generic.

CPU cooling: Coolermaster Siedon 120V

Graphics: Nvidia GeForce GTX 570 (base speed and specs.)

CPU: AMD FX 8350

Mobo: MSI 970A-G43 PLUS

HDD: 1 TB western digital 7200 rpm SATA

SSD: Sandisk 16GB 2.5in SATA SSD cannibalized from a Chromebook

OS: Windows 10

other: 1 wireless networking card (PCIe x1)

Answer (score 0):

Heat could definitely damage your CPU but they also have thermal protection and I would expect the system to shut off if the CPU overheated. I'd be more concerned about shortening it's life with sustained high heat situations, rather than a catastrophic failure from a single high heat incident.

I would look elsewhere for the issue. Depending on the issue, you may be able to isolate if it is a hardware or software issue by running various tests outside of windows or in safe mode - live boot discs, memory tests, etc.  You could also run a benchmark tool to see how it performs compared to similar components. I like [Passmark](https://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm), you can use a demo.

As far as the cooler not starting - well I think that is due to a defective pump. When you power cycle the computer the motherboard probably kicks the "fan" on high and that gets it spinning initially, but out of standby it probably doesn't experience that brief bump of power and never gets to spinning.

I'd be concerned about this thing seizing up, but it's also possible you just need to set a higher minimum fan speed in the BIOS. Your motherboard has fan speed adjustments available. Setting a higher minimum speed might insure it spins all the time. Check pages 1-22 and 2-7 in the [manual](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/support/970A-G43#down-manual). A pump is not a fan and probably requires more force to get it to spin, so the system will have to push it a little harder.

With that said, if the CPU gets hot it should try to kick the fan on higher which should get the pump spinning. So, I still really question if the CPU actually overheated. Very hot to us is not all that hot in electronics. If it didn't exceed 105 degrees Celsius it is probably absolutely fine.

In regards to getting parts replaced under warranty. That will be specific to the manufacturer. You could certainly try. But if they can detect that the CPU was overheated they could deny your claim.

Comment: small detail I forgot to add: I' had this computer for a few months, and this never happened until about 2 weeks ago. I'll add the story behind it in the question details.   regarding the cooler being set too low, I configured the CPU fan in the BIOS so that it would always run at 100%.

Comment: Yes but, "used to work" does not mean "still working."

Comment: Oh I also set the fan profile to be as high as possible when (CPUtemp ≥ 0)

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I may have overreacted. I let the computer sit for an hour, and it works just fine. I am starting to suspect that the sudden shutdown and reboot caused the processor to remain at a high heat when the computer restarted, causing thermal throttling to become high and stay high until the CPU "chilled" and the fact that it stayed throttled abnormally long was just a slow-to update CPU.